# Calling function that stores integers in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, scanf

I have a homework assignment that I need assistance with.

I have written a function that should take user input using scanf and store it into an array. It will also count the number of times an integer is entered (except 0, which terminates the program)
I am specifically having an issue calling this function within main()
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

I've tried using defining the function at the bottom, and using different variables within the function: `getVals`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 20 //defines the size of the array to 20

int nVals = 0;
int getVals(int myVals[], int maxVals);
int input[ARRAYSIZE+1] = {'0'};

int getVals(int myVals[], int maxVals)
{
  for (maxVals = 0; maxVals < ARRAYSIZE; maxVals++) { //When the row is    less than ten, it will run the loop and increment the row
    printf("Please Enter up to 20 integers "); //which will allow the name to be stored in the next row
    scanf("%d", &myVals[maxVals]);

    if ((myVals[maxVals] <= 0) || (maxVals == ARRAYSIZE -1))
       return nVals;
    if (myVals[maxVals] > 0)
       nVals++;

  }
}

int main() {
  printf("This program will receive up to 20 inputs from you, and sort them from least to greatest\n\n");
  printf("Enter 0 or a negative number to exit the program.\n");

  getVals(int ARRAYSIZE, int input[ARRAYSIZE]);

  printf("You have entered %d numbers\n", nVals);
  printf("%d", input[]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("Now sorting....\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is tangential to your problem, but… —— Note that the line `int input[ARRAYSIZE+1] = {'0'};` initializes `input[0]` to `48` and leaves the other elements all at 0.  You should write `0` and not `'0'` when you mean zero.  Technically, you could use `'\0'` and get the "all zeros" result, but that would be an idiosyncratic choice of notation and rather ill-advised.  Use `'\0'` when you're working with characters; use `0` when you're working with integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find a tutorial. They are full of code samples and you could control how simple things are done in them when unsure.

First the errors.

A function *declaration* just declares the function and its arguments. You use it correctly. You can have has many declaration for the same function in the same program, provided all are consistent.

A function *definition* contains the code for the function. A program should contain exactly one definition per function. BTW, a definition is also a declaration

A function call is where the function is used. It is no longer a declaration, and a declaration for the function must be visible before the call. You must pass existing variables consistent with the declaration.

Here you should have:

```
int input[ARRAYSIZE];          // declare an int array
getVals(input, ARRAYSIZE);     // call the function
```

This line `printf("%d", input[]);` is wrong too. Arrays are not first class citizens in C language, and you can only print (or read) one element at a time. At least you should write `printf("%d", input);` (it as a call and not a declaration so it requires actual parameters and not formal ones). But the array would decay to a pointer to its first element (fine until there), the pointer will be converted to an int value (the address of the first element of the array) and you would print that value. Not what you want :-(

But there are other possible improvements.

`nVal` is a global value. Globals should be avoided unless you have a strong design reason to have one. Best practices recommend to pass parameters to function instead. So you should remove the gloval `int nVals = 0` change `getVals` to:

```
int getVals(int myVals[], int maxVals)
{
    int nVals;
    for (nVals = 0; nVals < maxVals; nVals++) { //When the row is    less than ten, it will run the loop and increment the row
        printf("Please Enter up to 20 integers "); //which will allow the name   to be stored in the next row
        if (1 != scanf("%d", &myVals[nVals])) {    // ALWAYS test scanf return value
            printf("Incorrect input");
            break;
        }
        if (myVals[nVals] <= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return nVals;
}
```

and call it from main as:

```
int nVals = getVals(input, ARRAYSIZE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I made some adjustments and the function works. One more specific question: why would I replace ARRAYSIZE in the loop, with maxVals, if I need only up to 20 inputs? maxVals isn't defined as 20 like ARRAYSIZE is.

Comment: @TRADEMARKsage: The responsability of the size of the passed buffer should be in caller and not in callee. And in main, I pass `ARRAYSIZE` for the formal parameter `maxVals`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem in `main()`

As [Rishi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9579729/rishi) noted in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335347/), one line at fault is this line in `main()`:

```
getVals(int ARRAYSIZE, int input[ARRAYSIZE]);
```

This should prevent your code compiling, because after the preprocessor is finished, the line reads:

```
getVals(int 20, int input[20]);
```

That is not valid C, at all — the first `20` is a meaningless syntactic error.

Assuming you have something that more or less compiles, such as either of these:

```
getVals(int SIZE, int input[ARRAYSIZE]);
getVals(int SIZE, int input[SIZE]);
```

then you have a function declaration without a return type.  Under C90 rules, that couldn't appear in the middle of a function.  Under C99 or later rules, it can appear where it does, but it should have a return type –

```
int getVals(int SIZE, int input[ARRAYSIZE]);
int getVals(int SIZE, int input[SIZE]);
```

The first of the declarations is valid in both C90 and C99, though the `ARRAYSIZE` is immaterial.  The second of the declarations is only valid in C99 or later, because it uses a VLA (variable length array).  Those did not exist in C90.

However, because this is a declaration and not a function call, the actual `getVals()` function is never called — which is your reported problem.

You actually want:

```
int num = getVals(ARRAYSIZE, input);
```

**Except:**

You've defined `getVals()` using:

```
int getVals(int myVals[], int maxVals)
```

so you really need to call:

```
getVals(input, ARRAYSIZE);
```

#### Problems in `getVals()`

This function is a mess too.  You should probably use something like:

```
int getVals(int myVals[], int maxVals)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < maxVals; i++)
    {
        printf("Please Enter up to 20 integers ");
        if (scanf("%d", &myVals[i]) != 1)
            return i;
        if (myVals[i] <= 0)
            return i;
        nVals++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

I've retained `nVals` as a global variable, but it really isn't necessary.  You should avoid global variables (variables defined outside of any function) whenever possible.

Answer (score -1):

Error: in this line in main function

```
getVals(int ARRAYSIZE, int input[ARRAYSIZE]);
```

The correct way:

```
getVals(input, input[ARRAYSIZE]);
```

First: you shouldn't use data type to your attribute when you call the function.

Second: Your array name is "input", as you're passing array so you should use array name that is input not ARRAYSIZE...

Comment: Note that `input[ARRAYSIZE]` in the 'corrected' call accesses a value outside the bounds of the array.  If you used `ARRAYSIZE` as the second argument to `getVals()` — so you use `getVals(input, ARRAYSIZE);` — you'd be mostly correct on one of the many problems in the OP's code.